# SWIFT 3 and Firebase using tableEdit mode to insert data to firebase which updates my table array for tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3

SWIFT 3 and Firebase - I'm trying to use the UITable inEditing mode to insert cells into firebase and have a firebase listener that updates my arraty.  My insertions to fire base are fine, but I keep getting an index out of range when I try to do the insertion with the new add button i created.  Has anyone used Firebase with UITable inEditing mode to insert into a table and update firebase.

This is what I looking for:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWcw8.png)

The problem maybe be how I wrote the cellForAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("zzz indexPath index path row: \(indexPath.row)")
    print("zzz indexPath name \(myPins[indexPath.row].pinName)")
    print("ZZZ myPins Count \(myPins.count)")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PinCell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row == 0 && isEditing {
        //this means we are in editing mode an we to add the cell that will be addPlace
        //let indexPathOfFirstRow = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Add Place"
        print("add place was called index.row is : \(indexPath.row)")  
    } else {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PinCell", for: indexPath)
        let pin = myPins[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = pin.pinName
    }

    return cell
}
```

i get this error message: fatal error: Index out of range

Here is the rest of the table set up code:

```
   //When the use press the editing button it will make the table enditable

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        //if the viw is in editing mode then we will set the table to be in enditing mode.  

        if isEditing {

            //This is adding the addtional cell in for add place

            tableView.beginUpdates()

           let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

          // self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPathOfFirstRow], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

           tableView.endUpdates()

            tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)


        } else {

            //when the 'Done' is pressed this will take away the add button 

            tableView.beginUpdates()

            let indexPathOfFirstRow = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPathOfFirstRow], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

            tableView.endUpdates()

            //otherwise the table will not be in editing mode. 
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        //STEP 1 for adding a row that will fuction as add place
        //If we are in editing mode a 1 will be return and the extra cell will be added
        let adjustment = isEditing ? 1 : 0

        //add the extra cell if we are in editing mode
        return myPins.count + adjustment

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PinCell", for: indexPath)

        if indexPath.row == 0 && isEditing {
            //this means we are in editing mode an we to add the cell that will be addPlace

                //let indexPathOfFirstRow = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

                cell.textLabel?.text = "Add Place"
            print("add place was called index.row is : \(indexPath.row)")
            //addCell.addButton.tag = indexPath.row
            //addCell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: "addPlace", for: .touchUpInside)


        } else {

     //   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PinCell", for: indexPath)

        //this is the info I want to dispaly in the cell

        let pin = myPins[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = pin.pinName

        return cell

    }



    //add the green plus button icon for the extra row added

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {


       // let indexRow = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return .insert
        }

        return .delete
    }

    //delete with a with a swipe
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("pins count before deleate\(myPins.count)")


        if editingStyle == .delete {


            let pin = myPins[indexPath.row]

            guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {return}

            rootRef.child(child.users.rawValue).child(currentUser).child(users.myPins.rawValue).child(plotToEdit!.plotID).child(pin.placeID).removeValue()


        }


            //When you press on the green plus button as appose to the row.

            else if editingStyle == .insert {

            let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
            autocompleteController.delegate = self
            present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    }

    //When in ending more I can slect the first row that is add places 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {

       // let indexPathOfFirstRow = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

        if isEditing && (indexPath.row > 0) {
           return nil
        }
        return indexPath

    }
```

Comment: When you setValue to Firebase, are you also adding the item to the array directly or do you have a .childAdded event that updates (adds) to the array? It's not clear from the code how the data is being added, so my guess is your array indexes go out of scope - possibly when the tableView is returning the numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using the childAdded method and its updating the array.  so its probably messing up the number of rows in section.   Here is how I was able to add in the additional row for the 'add place' Cell:       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        //STEP 1 for adding a row that will fuction as add place

        let adjustment = isEditing ? 1 : 0
        
        //add the extra cell if we are in editing mode
        return myPins.count + adjustment
        
    }

Comment: Can you add the code in your comment to your question please?

Comment: I added the rest of the table set up.

Comment: It looks like the code is accessing a row past the last row in your array (need to confirm that). However, using the first row of a tableView as a function to add additional rows may not be best practice. I would encourage you to add a + button in your UI to add additional rows - it will make the whole process much smoother and more maintainable and require less code.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm new to this.  That is what I ended up doing. The look I was going for was Apple Music.  When you wan to add a song to an additional play list a row will pop up with an add button.  Is there a way you can make the add button only show in edit mode?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that - like inserting a dummy blank row at index 0 of your dataSource array and removing it when leaving edit mode. When in edit mode, have cellForRowAt populate cell 0 with the plus button image. Then you don't have to worry about worrying about returning the myPins.count + adjustment. You just return myPins.count.